# Reversing Order of Strings in two dimensional array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, reverse

I'm trying to reverse the order of strings in an array. I get the error: Index 3 out of bounds for length 1. This works for int if I use numbers but not for words. Could you help me out?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here


        String [][] arr = {{"My"}, {"name" }, {"is"}, {"John"}};

        String arr1 = arr[0][3];
        String arr2 = arr[0][2];
        String arr3 = arr[0][1];
        String arr4 = arr[0][0];
        String arrAll = arr1+arr2+arr3+arr4;
        System.out.println(arrAll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why a 2d array ??

Comment: You got your indices wrong. just swap 1st and 2nd index, and it should work. [Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/Br1Nnd)

Answer (score 1):

Think of a 2 dimensional array, in java, as a matrix that consists of rows and columns. In order to find out how many rows are in `arr`, use the following code.

```java
arr.length
```

You will find that this will return 4.

To get the first row in `arr`, use the following code.

```java
arr[0]
```

Similarly, to get the second row, use the following code.

```java
arr[1]
```

Each row may have a different number of columns, although in the code in your question, each row has one column.

To get the number of columns in the first row, the code is

```java
arr[0].length
```

To get a single element in a two dimensional array you need both the row index and the column index, in that order. Hence to get the element in the first column of the first row, use the following

```java
arr[0][0]
```

Since there is only one column in the first row, the following will cause a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown.

```java
arr[0][1]
```

This explains why `arr[0][3]` is giving you an error. You are trying to access the element in the fourth column of the first row but the first row has only one column.

The following code will provide your desired result.

```
String[][] arr = {{"My"}, {"name" }, {"is"}, {"John"}};
int rows = arr.length;
System.out.println("rows = " + rows);
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    System.out.println("row " + i + " columns = " + arr[i].length);
}

String arr1 = arr[3][0];
String arr2 = arr[2][0];
String arr3 = arr[1][0];
String arr4 = arr[0][0];
String arrAll = arr1+arr2+arr3+arr4;
System.out.println(arrAll);
```

Running the above code produces the following.

```
rows = 4
row 0 columns = 1
row 1 columns = 1
row 2 columns = 1
row 3 columns = 1
JohnisnameMy
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to print the words, you just have to :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here
String [][] arr = {{"My"}, {"name" }, {"is"}, {"John"}};

    String [] arr1 = arr[3];
    String [] arr2 = arr[2];
    String [] arr3 = arr[1];
    String [] arr4 = arr[0];
    String arrAll = arr1[0]+arr2[0]+arr3[0]+arr4[0];
    System.out.println(arrAll);
}
```

Comment: `arr[i]` will be a `String[]`, not a `String`.

Comment: @Turing85 you right. i updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of array of strings.
So when you're accessing `arr[0]` you're accessing the first array of string `{"My"}`. So, the `arr[0][3]` tries to access the third element from the the first row of the array of array of string, which actually doesn't exists as the array of string has only one element `length 1`, hence you're getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

If you're trying to reverse the sentence, you can work with only first index of the arrays`arr[0],arr[1],arr[2] & arr[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to select the first element of each of the inner arrays.

So, first index you are giving must be the index of the inner array. Second one must be the index of the element in that inner array. In other words it is `arr[innerArrayIndex][elementIndex]` and since all of your inner arrays have only one element, second indexes must be zero.

```
    String arr1 = arr[3][0];
    String arr2 = arr[2][0];
    String arr3 = arr[1][0];
    String arr4 = arr[0][0];
```